# Cotangent property

Tags: trigonometry

If I have
$\cot(k(x-a+π+π/k))$

Then, is

$\cot(kx-ka+kπ+π)=\cot(kx-ka+kπ)=\cot(k(x-a+π))=\cot(k(x-a))$

correct if I use $\cot(a+π)=\cot(a)$ property?

Comment: That's not how the property works. Just check for $k=1/3$ then you are implying that $\cot{(y+\pi/3)}=\cot{(y)}$.

Comment: Oh thank goodness! So @Peter Foreman do I just keep $kπ$ as it is?

Comment: Yes, $\cot{(kx-ka+k\pi)}$ is as simplified as you can have unless $k$ is an integer.

Comment: How about $cot(a+nπ)$ can we use the above property here? @Peter Foreman

Comment: $\cot{(a+n\pi)}=\cot{(a)}$ if and only if $n$ is an integer.

Comment: @Peter Foreman, thank you!!